# OracleSQL cast new variable based on multiple columns using if

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with four variables `a,x1,x2,x3`. It is guaranteed that `x1 < x2 < x3` for each record. I want to create a new variable `y` where `y=1` if `a<x1`and `y=2`  if `x1 <= a < x2` and `y=3` if `x2 <= a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
case when a<x1 then 1
when x1<=a and a<x2 then 2
when x2<= a then 3
end as y
```

I believe a case statement is all that is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `case`:

```
(case when a < x1 then 1
      when a < x2 then 2
      else 3
 end) as y
```

Comment: so it would be `SELECT (case ...) as y FROM ...`, correct?

Comment: @SAFEX . . . Yes.

Answer (score 0):

If these are the columns of your table then you can always use the `virtual column` as follows:

```
SQL> -- Creating the table
SQL> create table tbl
  2  (a number,
  3  x1 number,
  4  x2 number,
  5  x3 number);

Table created.

SQL> -- inserting some data
SQL> insert into tbl(a,x1,x2,x3) values(0,1,2,3);

1 row created.

SQL> -- this is your solution
SQL> alter table tbl add y number generated always
  2  as (case when a<x1 then 1 when a<x2 then 2 when a<x3 then 3 end) VIRTUAL;

Table altered. 

SQL> -- table data now
SQL> select * from tbl;

         A         X1         X2         X3          Y
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         0          1          2          3          1

SQL>
```